# Optimizing Input Configurations for ESP32: External Pull-Up Resistor Considerations

Tags: esp32

As I'm using to many inputs I thinks it's not good to set all of them with the internal pull up mode. To avoid heating the microcontroller and because the ESP32 will be power by a battery.  Therefore, I've decided to employ external pull-up resistors. Now, the question that arises is, what is the optimal value? Would 100K be suitable for an external pull-up resistor?

This inquiry stems from the consideration that if the input impedance is 100K and an external pull-up resistor of 100K is used, the pin would register a value of Vcc/2. And if the internal pin impedance is 1MOhms and I use a 100K pull up resistor, the voltage at the pin would be Vcc*0.9. I'm seeking confirmation. A cursory examination online indicates that many projects opt for a value of 10KOhms for external pull up resistor.

I couldn't find this information in the ESP32 datasheet. Because I also interested in the input impedance of the ADCs.

Your insights and recommendations on this matter would be greatly appreciated.